# subclassing child window c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on windows and i chose the c++ as language. My application is a win32 application and I am not using MFC classes, but only the native API.

My main window contain a Tab control in which there is a Listview control. I tried to Subclass both the control, but it is not working even though i follow the msdn guide.

The function I used are:
`SetWindowLong` and `GetWindowLong` 
so I changed the child's procedures but it seems the main window catches every messages that controls send ( through WM_NOTIFY ) and every WM messages. I thought that it may concern focus but I do not have any idea on how implement this kind of situation: a child control which is the parent of an another child control.

I have created the Tab control in this way.
code:

```
hwndTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, "",
    WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,
    0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
    winHandle, NULL, hInst, NULL);

OldUserTabProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(hwndTab, GWL_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLong(hwndTab, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)UserTabProc);
```

Here The Tab control procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK UserTabProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  switch ( message )
  {
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    break;
  case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    break;
  case TCN_SELCHANGE:
  {
    userCurrentTab = TabCtrl_GetCurSel( userTab );
    break;
  }
  case TCN_SELCHANGING:
  {
    break;
  }
  };

  return CallWindowProc( OldUserTabProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
```

The listview has as parent the Tab control.

Comment: your question is unclear, could you add simple code to explain your question!

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a great place to start.

Comment: Note that the basic API model is that a control sends messages to its parent, via e.g. `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY`. I.e. centralized handling, suitable for C. C++ GUI frameworks like MFC **reflect** those messages back to the control for local distributed handling, suitable for C++.

Comment: local distributed handling? thanks all for the answers.

Comment: local handling = distributed. central handling = like, centralized.

Comment: @CheersAndHth, very true with C++. That said, if you need to subclass to change the behaviour of a control, odd's are that you don't find MFC that'd do it.

Comment: If you're calling `SetWindowLong` to subclass a control, you're doing it wrong. See [Subclassing Controls Using ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx#subclassing_v6).

Comment: I read it. The problem is that I chose the ANSI charset( and I can't use it but with UNICODE ). However I am not really sure that if I changed it, i'd solve everything. if it's the only thing I can do, it's worth a try. thank you

Comment: At the end I switched the charset to UNICODE and it's finally working, using SetWindowSubclass. Or better, the messages are finally caught by the expective procedures. Thank you for all the advise!

Answer (score 0):

Values like `TCN_SELCHANGE` are not message types and they aren't sent to the control themselves.  They are notifications (the `N` stands for "notification").  Notifications are sent by the control to the parent using a message like `WM_NOTIFY` or `WM_COMMAND`.  You cannot intercept them by subclassing the control.

If you want to change the way the parent handles those notifications, you need to subclass the parent.

Comment: it's a mistake. I copied erroneously the WM_NOTIFY message, but the problem persist with the WM_ messages( e.g WM_LBUTTONDOWN )

Comment: You're saying that the parent window receives the WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages rather than the control?  That shouldn't happen.  How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I set 2 breakpoints: one on WM_LBUTTONDOWN of the parent and the other one on that of the control. Only the first one is caught, whereas the other is ignored( the program doesn't stop on the breakpoint ). I thought it has to be a focus' matter but, since I have a control that will become the parent of an another control, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Does the control have WS_EX_TRANSPARENT?  That would cause the mouse clicks to go to the parent.

Comment: I do not even have WS_EX_TRANSPARENT. I was actually thinking that I could put every control as child of the main window but it seems excessive and might not solve the problem.